# clang_getCursorType does not recognize std:: types

Tags: clang, libclang

I'm playing with `libclang` and I ran into a weird problem.

I wrote a small parser with `libclang` and in my visitor passed to `clang_parseTranslationUnit` I have:

```
    CXChildVisitResult visitor(CXCursor cursor, CXCursor, CXClientData)
    {
        const auto cursorKind = clang_getCursorKind(cursor);

        if (cursorKind == CXCursor_FieldDecl)
        {
            const CXType cxtype = clang_getCursorType(cursor);
            std::cout << clang_getCString(clang_getTypeSpelling(cxtype)) << \n";            
        }

        return CXChildVisit_Continue;
    }
```

It works almost fine. If I parse a file:

```
#include <vector>

class AAA
{
public:
    std::vector<int> a;
    float b;
};
```

it prints `int` when visiting `a` member which is of type `std::vector<int>`.
I've check for many various template containers from `std` and it behaves like that for all of them. From the other side there is no problem if I, for example, use containers from `Qt` like `QList<int>`.

What can be wrong here?
I use libclang 16.0.6 on linux.

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your parser the include path to the standard library, which it needs to find the header file for `vector`.